# What does "go down drunk rabbit hole" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm studying english watching netflix drama "Emily in Paris" season 1.

I want to know the exact meaning of an expression in the conversion between Emily and Mindy.

---

**Situation before the conversation.**

Mindy who comes from china is the friend of Emily.

She was on Chinese Idol show and choked in front of chinese people.

After that, she has PTSD to sing a song.

Emily encourages Mindy to sing a song again.

So, Mindy decide to get an audition and find something to open an audition.

---

**My Question**

Mindy tells Emily that "I **went down a drunk rabbit hole** of goolgling jazz clubs in Paris"

(Then Mindy drunk and tried to find auditions in jazz clubs)

I found out and the understood the meaning of **"go down a rabbit hole"** in a dictionary and Alice's Adventures in Wonderland.

I want to know the exact meaning of **"go down a `drunk` rabbit hole"**.

Does the meaning change when **`drunk`** is added?

Or Was it simply expressing that Mindy was drinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression "falling (or going) down a rabbit hole" does refer to Alice in Wonderland, but specifically it means getting sucked into a never-ending activity - similar to the seemingly bottomless hole that Alice falls down.

In this case the activity is Googling all the jazz clubs in Paris.

The only relevance of "drunk" here is that Mindy only got started doing this because she had been drinking.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

"Going down the rabbit hole" is an allusion to *Alice in Wonderland*, and means "begin a process that is strange, complex or chaotic".

So Mindy means that the Jazz clubs are strange or chaotic.  But she is entering this situation when drunk (and therefore less able to deal with complexity). It is just expressing that Mindy had been drinking.

"Go down the rabbit hole" is an expression, but adding "drunk" to it is not a standard expression.